# how to know possibility of waking up in a certain hour using java

Tags: android, sleep, alarm

I want to make android application to tell me what is the possibility to walk up at fajr time (its prayer time for Muslims), I read about sleep stages and knew that there are 4 sleep stages (Awake, light, deep and rem), each stage takes a duration I want to calculate if this certain time is between the light stage or not, its technically simple but how to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

All these sleep cycles are determined mainly by heart beat per minute, so you can create a android watch app which monitors heart beats or you can see if the users smart watch has any APIs which lets you access these informations for example fitbit API https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/

Depending on this and the users FAJR time you can derive your information.

Comment: no I need to make it more global, not every one have a smart watch even if not all smart watches has API so its not suitable for me, I want to make it mathematically some how, we can consider that the start time to calculate the probability on it the user give it to the app so we solved one problem, we have the start time and the end time (FAJR time its known) remain the equation that will calculate the probability.